# How To get data From form password text in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css, visual-studio-2010

Hi I have problem with getting Data from a password textbox this it my asp Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and this is my C# Code in Code site

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtConfirmPassword"]))
{ string pass = nvc["txtConfirmPassword"].ToString(); }
```

and always the result  `nvc["txtConfirmPassword"] = null`  I can't get the password value in the code site 
please any one can help me

Answer (score 1):

You can access the enter text by using **.Text** property.

```
string strConfirmPass = txtConfirmPassword.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value by using the control's ID, so...

```
var password = txtConfirmPassword.Text;
```

It might not be seen in the form value collection due to transformed identifiers due to containers etc. but I don't see any particular reason why access would be attempted in that way.

Answer (score -1):

For security reasons the password is not displayed in asp.net and you can not get the value after postback.

you can work around this by adding the password value to the control as as Attribute. Since the TextBox renders as an HTML input control, you can set the value attribute easily, just as you would set the Text property.

```
  txtConfirmPassword.Attributes.Add("value", "yourRealPassword");
```

Use this to set the value, instead of setting the Text property. You can still read the value from the control via the Text property.

EDIT -

On the bases of comments, I am going edit my answer for better explanation 
In ASP.NET Password TextBox loses value after Postback , here are few links to support this statement

[ASP:TextBox Value disappears in postback only when password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169568/asptextbox-value-disappears-in-postback-only-when-password)

and here is a link which will explain How-to safely keep a password field during postback

[codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18927/How-to-safely-keep-a-password-field-during-postbac)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes you can get the value.

Comment: ASP.NET Password TextBox loses value after Postback.. are you sure you can get it after postback?

Comment: Positive... how would you ever authenticate anything with it?

Comment: from experience and from many links :) like ... http://addinit.com/node/43  and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18927/How-to-safely-keep-a-password-field-during-postbac