# Request.Form does not work on type password

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi everyone I used Request.Form function to get type password and whenever I write something the string I get is empty so when I update something it deletes it. it does work when i change the type to text. MyAdohelper is a sheet that do some actions, ignore.

ASPX file:

```
Enter your username please:
<input type="text" id="usName1" name="usName1" placeholder="Your username" />

Enter your new password please:
<input type="text" id="newpass" name="newpass" placeholder="Your new password" />
```

CS file:

```
if (Request.Form["submit"] != null)
{
    string usName1 = Request.Form["usName1"];
    string newpass = Request.Form["newpass"];
    string update = "UPDATE [info1] SET Password = '" + newpass + "' WHERE usName= '" + usName1 + "'";
    string csql = "SELECT usName FROM [info1] WHERE usName='" + usName1 + "'";
    if (MyAdoHelper.IsExist("Database.mdf", csql))
    {
        MyAdoHelper.DoQuery("Database.mdf", update);
        msg = "success";
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        msg = "We cannot find your username";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `type="text"` for a password instead of `type="password"`?

Comment: I used type=text just to check if it will work and it does but i need type password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To get data From form password text in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522413/how-to-get-data-from-form-password-text-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

From [How To get data From form password text in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522413/how-to-get-data-from-form-password-text-in-asp-net)

@Ajay answer:

> You can access the enter text by using **.Text** property.
>
> ```
> string strConfirmPass = txtConfirmPassword.Text;
> ```

So, in your case it should be

```
string newpass_str = newpass.Text;
```

Notice that I changed the string `newpass` to `newpass_str` since `newpass` is the id of the input field, that is, the identifier already exists.

Also, be warned that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: don't worry about injection lol and thx its only for school work

Comment: didnt quite catch what you wrote would you mind trying explaining differently

Comment: @YetivAharon I don't know what you didn't catch. Just replace `Request.Form["newpass"]` to `newpass.Text` and you're done.

Comment: .Text does not work, Compiler Error CS1061 Visual Studio

Comment: Are you considering the conflict in variable names? If you declare a variable named newpass in local scope, the reference will point to it.