# Password filled blank after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I set the `textmode = Password` the value of the textbox is lost after the postback since 
as I know the textbox class implement the interface `IpostbcakdataHandler` so that it retains the value either we disable the textbox viewstate false.

So I want to know the reason why it is happening.

Comment: This has been asked before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169568/asptextbox-value-disappears-in-postback-only-when-password

Comment: When  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword", TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox> the value of the txtPassword has been last after postback i want to know the case,Is their any thing happen in page life cycle that made the blank the text box value.

Comment: Password being 'lost' after postback is by design and is a security measure. This is fairly common and is seen on many sites online.

Comment: pls see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169568/asptextbox-value-disappears-in-postback-only-when-password

Comment: It is good to enter password on postback, as the user can confirm each time he enters it.

Comment: Yes i know the but at which event of page or anything written the class of the text box that made the text box value blank when i set the text mode =password i want to know where it is written

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want to know how vs. why?  Have you tried checking out the MVC source code at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/?  Not exactly the same platform but seeing the implementation might answer your questions.